# Triggering animation only its position changes?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I am a newbie on coding, wanted to work on a game as practice and started to work on a 2D top view game, and on a barren desert area, I have a *Twigball* for my player to touch and move it because of its dynamic rigidbody.

This *Twigball* has 2 animations which those are **idle** and **movement** animations. Everytime my player touches, *Twigball* moves, changes its position. But what I need is: Everytime this *Twigball* moves by touching or any other ways, I want its *"isMoving"* bool is *"true"* and make it start the **"movement"** animation, everytime it stops, I want to start its **"idle"** animation.

It might be simple thing but I couldn't find how to do it with code. Rigidbody works good with its options (linear drag, angular drag etc...) on inspector. I have a `TwigBallBehaviour` script attached to the TwigBall but its empty. OnColliderEnter would work for Player touches etc. but this *Twigball* will also move itself as behaviour. So I need codes to do all that I think, probably calculating position etc... I have already done all changes in Animator window. But what should I write as code? Any advices?

Comment: Sounds like you should show us your TwigBallBehaviour code.

Answer (score 1):

Well I dealt with the problem, here the solution:

I wrote many codes to `TwigBallsBehaviour` which it was empty before, here the codes I wrote:

```
public class TwigBallsBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Animator anim;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool isMoving;
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim.SetBool("isMoving", false);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(rb.velocity.x == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isMoving", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isMoving", true);
        }

    }

}
```

I also added a code group to the Player's Script, used simply collisions. You can see below:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "TwigBall")
        {
            Debug.Log("Turning");
            if (transform.position.x < collision.gameObject.transform.position.x)
            {
                Debug.Log("From Right");

            }
            else
            {
                collision.gameObject.transform.parent.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -180, 0);
                Debug.Log("From Left");
            }

        }
    }
```

After all these, added collider to *TwigBall*, tagged it as "TwigBall". This is how I solved my problem.